# Excel Dynamic Search Formula

Tags: excel, search, formula

I am attempting to create a search function without using VBA and just using formulas for a contacts list. Any clarification on the breakdown of the formula would also help as I am new to using excel formulas. I have been trying to figure out something that checks all of these boxes but it is always missing one of the following. Information and requirements are as follows:

- There are 6 columns of data in a separate worksheet. For reference, the search box is in B2. The entire array of data is located at Directory!A3:F1000 (technically through F63 but I wanted to be exhaustive). I am just having these results re-displayed in the worksheet I am using the formulas at the bottom.

My requirements are as follows:

1. Search non case-sensitive matches.
2. Search partial text matches.
3. Replace all blank values, that show as zeroes, as blanks instead.
4. Sort all entries in alphabetical order.
5. Searches all columns for a value matching the searched value and returns all results as the entire row's entry.
6. Return "None" or "No results" if nothing matches the search results.

Optional
7. Hide search results if search box is blank. I know this can be achieved with conditional formatting but I was hoping for a 'cleaner' solution.

This is the formula I am using currently, but it **does not show partial text matches**. I was also not using a text box previously so the results were not automatically populating without hitting enter, this should now be fixed however:

```
=IF(SORT(FILTER(Directory!A3:F997,(Directory!A3:A997=B2)+(Directory!B3:B997=B2)+(Directory!C3:C997=B2)+(Directory!D3:D997=B2)+(Directory!E3:E997=B2)+(Directory!F3:F997=B2),"None"))=0,"",SORT(FILTER(Directory!A3:E997,(Directory!A3:A997=B2)+(Directory!B3:B997=B2)+(Directory!C3:C997=B2)+(Directory!D3:D997=B2)+(Directory!E3:E997=B2)+(Directory!F3:F997=B2),"None")))
```

These are not all the formulas I tried, but another I tried is as follows. Only issue was I could not figure out **how to add AND/OR formulas to use the SEARCH function for multiple columns**:

```
=IF(SORT(FILTER(Directory!A3:F1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!A3:A1000)),"None"))=0,"",SORT(FILTER(Directory!A3:F1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!A3:A1000)),"None")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I was able to sort it in the actual directory and all other issues were solved by switching to `ISNUMBER(SEARCH)`. I just wish I had a VBA to automatically sort two columns with an array instead of a table any time new data is entered.

```
=IF(FILTER(Directory!A4:F1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!A4:A1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!B4:B1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!C4:C1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!D4:D1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!E4:E1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!E4:E1000)),"No results")=0,"",(FILTER(Directory!A4:F1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!A4:A1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!B4:B1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!C4:C1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!D4:D1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!E4:E1000))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,Directory!E4:E1000)),"No results")))
```